# PSSA: Applying custom rules in the vscode powershell extension

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, powershell-5.0

I'm attempting to do custom rules and code formatting (using the `Format Document` tool) with powershell in vscode.  I've read quite a bit of the `PSScriptAnalyzer` and extension documentation, but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

If I manually run

```
Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer .\Example.ps1 -CustomRulePath .\Rule.psm1
```

`PSSA` recognizes the violation.  After changing the settings path, I don't get any highlighting while code formatting still appears to work.

How do I get the `settingsPath` to use custom rules and is it possible to use `PSSA` to set up custom code formatting (I've seen this advertised but not documented/blog posts about it)?

---

*`.\Example.ps1`*

```
function Get-MYVar {

    param (
    [string]$VariableName

)

    $results = $null

Get-Variable -Name $VariableName

}
```

---

*`.\Rule.psm1`*

```
using module @{ModuleName = 'PSScriptAnalyzer'; ModuleVersion = '1.17'}
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language
using namespace Microsoft.Windows.PowerShell.ScriptAnalyzer.Generic

function FunctionCasing
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([DiagnosticRecord[]])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ScriptBlockAst]
        $ScriptBlockAst
    )

    try
    {
        @($ScriptBlockAst.FindAll({
            $args[0] -is [FunctionDefinitionAst] -and
            $args[0].Name -cmatch '[A-Z]{2,}'
        }, $false)).ForEach({
            [DiagnosticRecord]@{
                Message  = 'Avoid function names with adjacent caps in their name'
                Extent   = $PSItem.Extent
                RuleName = $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName
                Severity = 'Warning'
            }
        })
    }
    catch
    {
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($PSItem)
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function FunctionCasing
```

---

*`.\Rule.psd1`*

```
@{
    IncludeRules = @('Rule.psm1')
}
```

*`.\.vscode\settings.json`*

```
{
    "powershell.scriptAnalysis.settingsPath": "..\\Rule.psd1"
}
```

Comment: `settings.json` references `MyRule.psd1`, it should be 'Rule.psd1'. And `Rule.psd1` references 'MyRule.psm1', it should be 'Rule.psm1'

Comment: @JuanMellado That's only an error with my question; the project has the right names, I just stripped out the `my` part I was copying.  I've updated it now